# How to stop Duplicate class found error when adding selenium to dependancies (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, selenium-webdriver

I am doing a tutorial on how to use selenium but when I add the selenium dependancy in build.gradle

"implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.141.0'"

I get the following error message:

Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable

and

Duplicate class com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture found in modules guava-25.0-jre (com.google.guava:guava:25.0-jre) and listenablefuture-1.0 (com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0)

To me this seems like there is two "listenablefuture" classes causing this error. How do I solve this issue?

I am using a brand new empty activity with no code apart from the default "hello world" in the xml